# Eclipse not showing all problems from Pylint

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pylint

I am currently trying to get Pylint to work with Eclipse.
I can see the output of Pylint in the console all right, but in the Problems view a lot of the messages are missing. For example in one file I have more than 500 messages in the console, and only 12 problems in the Problems view.

I have the Warnings/Conventions/Refactor severities put to Warnings in the pylint configuration of Eclipse. Use Pylint and Redirect Pylint output to the console are both checked.

To be sure I don't provide a pylintrc file.

My versions are:

Ubuntu 12.04

Eclipse 3.7.2

PyDev 2.8.2.2013090511

Pylint 0.25.0

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance you can update PyDev? I remember that PyLint changed its format, so, the older PyDev (2.8.2) may not be able to work with it... (can't you upgrade PyDev/PyLint? -- this should make things easier to get support).

Note that PyDev now requires java 7 and at least Eclipse 3.8 (if it's hard to get things up to date, you may want to check LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ which gives you an Eclipse standalone with PyDev bundled).

Comment: Well, I succeeded installing Eclipse v4.3, the latest PyDev 3.6, and it still doesn't work. I tried installing LiClipse, but its the same. The thing is that I can't upgrade pylint, which is only at version 0.25 in Ubuntu Precise (12.04).

Comment: When you redirect the output to the console, does something appear in the console? Is there some error in your error log? (see http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for how to get the error log)

Comment: Another thing: you may have to add '--include-ids=y' to the arguments (as it's an older version of PyLint).

Comment: Well you made my day !!! Actually, adding --include-ids=y did the trick. Thank you very much for your help, I didn't found it anywhere.